Android app crashes on launch: SELinux and encryption policy errors in logcat
Android app crashes on launch: SELinux and encryption policy errors in logcat
I'm attempting to run an open-source Android project from GitHub on both my physical Android device and an Android Virtual Device (AVD), but I'm encountering immediate crashes upon launch. The logcat reveals multiple errors which I'm struggling to resolve.
Environment

AVDixel 6 Pro Api 30
Android Studio version:  Android Studio Jelyfish 2023.3.1( working better than ladybug for me )

Logcat Errors
Here are some of the most significant errors from the logcat:
2024-10-06 10:11:12.069 0-0 [Firmware Bug] kernel E CPU1: APIC id mismatch. Firmware: 1 APIC: 0 --------- beginning of main
2024-10-06 10:11:21.437 0-0 init kernel E Failed to copy /avb into /metadata/gsi/dsu/avb/: No such file or directory
2024-10-06 10:11:22.485 0-0 init kernel E [libfs_avb]Device path not found: /dev/block/by-name/system
2024-10-06 10:11:23.533 0-0 init kernel E [libfs_avb]Device path not found: /dev/block/by-name/system
2024-10-06 10:11:24.587 0-0 selinux kernel E SELinux: Could not get canonical path for /metadata/ota/rollback-indicator restorecon: No such file or directory.
2024-10-06 10:11:24.590 0-0 selinux kernel E
2024-10-06 10:11:24.591 0-0 selinux kernel E SELinux: Could not stat /metadata/gsi: No such file or directory.
2024-10-06 10:11:24.594 0-0 selinux kernel E
2024-10-06 10:11:25.087 0-0 cgroup1 kernel E Unknown subsys name 'schedtune'
2024-10-06 10:11:25.090 0-0 libprocessgroup kernel E Failed to mount schedtune cgroup: Invalid argument
2024-10-06 10:11:29.293 154-154 cutils-trace hwservicemanager E Error opening trace file: Permission denied (13) --------- beginning of system 
2024-10-06 10:11:29.454 172-172 cutils-trace and...ardware.keymaster@4.1-service E Error opening trace file: Permission denied (13)
2024-10-06 10:11:29.966 162-162 vold vold E generate_key failed, code -67 
2024-10-06 10:11:36.355 0-0 init kernel E Unable to set property 'ro.boottime.init.fsck.data' from uid:0 gid:0 pid:162: Read-only property was already set
2024-10-06 10:11:36.376 0-0 init kernel E Unable to set property 'ro.boottime.init.mount.data' from uid:0 gid:0 pid:162: Read-only property was already set
2024-10-06 10:11:36.421 0-0 selinux kernel E SELinux: Could not stat /sys/kernel/debug: No such file or directory.
2024-10-06 10:11:36.423 0-0 selinux kernel E
2024-10-06 10:11:36.486 0-0 init kernel E Unable to set property 'ro.crypto.state' from uid:0 gid:0 pid:1: Read-only property was already set
2024-10-06 10:11:36.564 162-162 vold vold E generate_key failed, code -67 
2024-10-06 10:11:36.596 0-0 init kernel E Failed to set encryption policy of /data/misc to 408f58ebeb6fa4b3e8f9949dbb6b175d v2 modes 1/4 flags 0x2: Directory not empty
2024-10-06 10:11:36.620 0-0 logwrapper kernel E executing ls failed: Permission denied
2024-10-06 10:11:36.625 0-0 logwrapper kernel E
2024-10-06 10:11:36.632 0-0 init kernel E ls -laZ /data/misc returned failure: 255
2024-10-06 10:11:36.634 0-0 init kernel E Setting 408f58ebeb6fa4b3e8f9949dbb6b175d policy on /data/misc failed!
2024-10-06 10:11:36.637 0-0 init kernel E Rebooting into recovery
2024-10-06 10:11:36.792 0-0 init kernel E Failed to set encryption policy of /data/system to 408f58ebeb6fa4b3e8f9949dbb6b175d v2 modes 1/4 flags 0x2: Directory not empty
2024-10-06 10:11:36.796 0-0 logwrapper kernel E executing ls failed: Permission denied
2024-10-06 10:11:36.802 0-0 logwrapper kernel E
2024-10-06 10:11:36.808 0-0 init kernel E ls -laZ /data/system returned failure: 255
2024-10-06 10:11:36.811 0-0 init kernel E Setting 408f58ebeb6fa4b3e8f9949dbb6b175d policy on /data/system failed!
2024-10-06 10:11:36.818 0-0 init kernel E Rebooting into recovery
2024-10-06 10:11:39.030 162-162 vold vold E generate_key failed, code -67 
2024-10-06 10:11:39.103 162-162 vold vold E generate_key failed, code -67 
2024-10-06 10:11:39.643 0-0 selinux kernel E SELinux: Could not stat /data/dalvik-cache/arm: No such file or directory.
2024-10-06 10:11:39.646 0-0 selinux kernel E
2024-10-06 10:11:39.647 0-0 selinux kernel E SELinux: Could not stat /data/dalvik-cache/arm64: No such file or directory.
2024-10-06 10:11:39.651 0-0 selinux kernel E
2024-10-06 10:11:39.652 0-0 selinux kernel E SELinux: Could not stat /data/dalvik-cache/mips: No such file or directory.
2024-10-06 10:11:39.655 0-0 selinux kernel E
2024-10-06 10:11:39.656 0-0 selinux kernel E SELinux: Could not stat /data/dalvik-cache/mips64: No such file or directory.
2024-10-06 10:11:39.660 0-0 selinux kernel E
2024-10-06 10:11:39.661 0-0 selinux kernel E SELinux: Could not stat /data/dalvik-cache/x86: No such file or directory.
2024-10-06 10:11:39.664 0-0 selinux kernel E
2024-10-06 10:11:39.666 0-0 selinux kernel E SELinux: Could not stat /data/dalvik-cache/x86_64: No such file or directory.
2024-10-06 10:11:39.669 0-0 selinux kernel E
2024-10-06 10:11:39.767 0-0 init kernel E Could not set 'ro.logd.size' to '2M' in /data/local.prop: Read-only property was already set
2024-10-06 10:11:39.771 0-0 init kernel E Could not load single persistent property file, trying legacy directory: Unable to read persistent property file: open() failed: No such file or directory
2024-10-06 10:11:40.058 274-274 LibBpfLoader pid-274 E No progs section could be found in elf object
2024-10-06 10:11:40.116 0-0 ueventd kernel E firmware: could not find firmware for regulatory.db
2024-10-06 10:11:40.118 0-0 ueventd kernel E firmware: attempted /etc/firmware/regulatory.db, open failed: No such file or directory
2024-10-06 10:11:40.122 0-0 ueventd kernel E firmware: attempted /odm/firmware/regulatory.db, open failed: No such file or directory
2024-10-06 10:11:40.136 0-0 ueventd kernel E firmware: attempted /vendor/firmware/regulatory.db, open failed: No such file or directory 
2024-10-06 10:11:40.140 0-0 ueventd kernel E firmware: attempted /firmware/image/regulatory.db, open failed: No such file or directory 
2024-10-06 10:11:40.228 0-0 init kernel E failed to write pid to files: couldn't write 287 to /dev/cpuset/camera-daemon/tasks: No such file or directory
2024-10-06 10:11:40.400 285-285 bt and...are.bluetooth@1.1-service.sim E system/bt/vendor_libs/test_vendor_lib/model/devices/device_properties.cc:83 DeviceProperties: Error reading controller properties from file.
2024-10-06 10:11:40.873 287-287 GCH_CameraProvider and...a.provider@2.6-service-google E Initialize: HWL doesn't support vendor buffer allocation Function not implemented(-38)
2024-10-06 10:11:40.968 298-298 EmuHWC2 and...graphics.composer@2.3-service E doGetFunction: Unknown function descriptor: 44 (SetLayerFloatColor)
2024-10-06 10:11:40.968 298-298 EmuHWC2 and...graphics.composer@2.3-service E doGetFunction: Unknown function descriptor: 45 (SetLayerPerFrameMetadata)
2024-10-06 10:11:40.968 298-298 EmuHWC2 and...graphics.composer@2.3-service E doGetFunction: Unknown function descriptor: 46 (GetPerFrameMetadataKeys)
2024-10-06 10:11:40.968 298-298 EmuHWC2 and...graphics.composer@2.3-service E doGetFunction: Unknown function descriptor: 47 (SetReadbackBuffer)
2024-10-06 10:11:40.968 298-298 EmuHWC2 and...graphics.composer@2.3-service E doGetFunction: Unknown function descriptor: 48 (GetReadbackBufferAttributes)
2024-10-06 10:11:40.968 298-298 EmuHWC2 and...graphics.composer@2.3-service E doGetFunction: Unknown function descriptor: 49 (GetReadbackBufferFence)
2024-10-06 10:11:40.968 298-298 EmuHWC2 and...graphics.composer@2.3-service E doGetFunction: Unknown function descriptor: 50 (GetRenderIntents)
2024-10-06 10:11:40.968 298-298 EmuHWC2 and...graphics.composer@2.3-service E doGetFunction: Unknown function descriptor: 51 (SetColorModeWithRenderIntent)
2024-10-06 10:11:40.968 298-298 EmuHWC2 and...graphics.composer@2.3-service E doGetFunction: Unknown function descriptor: 52 (GetDataspaceSaturationMatrix)
2024-10-06 10:11:40.968 298-298 EmuHWC2 and...graphics.composer@2.3-service E doGetFunction: Unknown function descriptor: 55 (SetLayerColorTransform)
2024-10-06 10:11:40.968 298-298 EmuHWC2 and...graphics.composer@2.3-service E doGetFunction: Unknown function descriptor: 56 (GetDisplayedContentSamplingAttributes)
2024-10-06 10:11:40.968 298-298 EmuHWC2 and...graphics.composer@2.3-service E doGetFunction: Unknown function descriptor: 57 (SetDisplayedContentSamplingEnabled)
2024-10-06 10:11:40.968 298-298 EmuHWC2 and...graphics.composer@2.3-service E doGetFunction: Unknown function descriptor: 58 (GetDisplayedContentSample)
2024-10-06 10:11:40.968 298-298 EmuHWC2 and...graphics.composer@2.3-service E doGetFunction: Unknown function descriptor: 59 (SetLayerPerFrameMetadataBlobs)
2024-10-06 10:11:41.053 286-286 EmulatedCamera_Factory and...e.camera.provider@2.4-service E 1 cameras are being emulated. 0 of them are fake cameras.
2024-10-06 10:11:41.054 286-286 CamPrvdr@2.4-legacy and...e.camera.provider@2.4-service E setUpVendorTags: Vendor tag operations not fully defined. Ignoring definitions.
2024-10-06 10:11:41.054 286-286 CamPrvdr@2.4-legacy and...e.camera.provider@2.4-service E initialize: Vendor tag setup failed, will not be available.
2024-10-06 10:11:41.066 286-348 EmulatedCa...plugThread and...e.camera.provider@2.4-service E addWatch: Could not add watch for '/data/misc/media/emulator.camera.hotplug.0', error: 'Permission denied' (13)
2024-10-06 10:11:41.156 0-0 init kernel E Unable to set property 'ro.hardware.egl' from uid:0 gid:0 pid:128: Read-only property was already set
2024-10-06 10:11:41.435 350-350 SurfaceFlinger surfaceflinger E ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
2024-10-06 10:11:41.559 350-350 HWComposer surfaceflinger E loadLayerMetadataSupport: getLayerGenericMetadataKeys failed: UNSUPPORTED (8)
2024-10-06 10:11:41.561 350-350 HWComposer surfaceflinger E isConnected failed for display 8141603649153536: Invalid display
2024-10-06 10:11:41.567 350-350 HWComposer surfaceflinger E getDisplayConnectionType: getDisplayConnectionType failed for display 8141603649153536: Unsupported (8)
2024-10-06 10:11:41.940 394-394 bootstat pid-394 E Failed to read /metadata/bootstat/persist.sys.boot.reason: No such file or directory 
2024-10-06 10:11:41.952 394-394 bootstat pid-394 E Failed to unlink /metadata/bootstat/persist.sys.boot.reason:

These errors were consisntenly reproduced on my  avd, but now my "AVD" keep starting up for hours
Attempted Solutions
I've already tried several common troubleshooting steps:

Cleaned and rebuilt the project
Invalidated caches and restarted Android Studio
Synced the project with Gradle files

However, none of these actions have resolved the issue. The app continues to crash immediately upon launch,
Any insights or suggestions on how to approach this problem would be greatly appreciated. I'm relatively new to Android development, and I'm finding these system-level errors particularly challenging to debug.
i tried to

Clean and rebuild the project
Invalidate caches and restart Android Studio
Sync the project with Gradle files
and any other possible solution to free spaces but nothing changed

i believe that with your guidance, my app is going to run again  .it's been 2 days without coding
